# prismJS not working with angularJS factory

Tags: angularjs

I have a project which has some codes to show. So I wanted to use prismJS a code highlighter. I make a angular directive for prism and it works fine when I write a code like

```
<pre><code ng-prism class="language-css">p{color:red;}</code></pre>
```

But I have a factory which may contain this line as a string and I want to render this string.
My factory like -

```
    .factory('myFactory',function(){
        var fact ={};
        var code = [
                {      
                  text:'<pre><code ng-prism class="language-css">p{color:red;}</code></pre>'
                 }
           ]
       fact.getCode = function(){
           return code;
       }
return fact;
    })
```

And my created directive is -

```
.directive('ngPrism', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            element.ready(function() {
                Prism.highlightElement(element[0]);
            });
        }
    }
  }])
```

Now I want to show the text code with code highlighting using prism. But I cannot.